# Is there any operation will cause css be loaded as async in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

ref: https://github.com/amireh/happypack/issues/202

The question is, I don't know why the css be loaded as async and how to solve this correctly

------------------Update----------------------

My question is, what reason cause my css be loaded as async, the 'async' means that when I open the url in the browser, I will see a page without css in a few seconds because the css will be loaded after the script execute the code about add style to head tag.

But in my all projects before, the css will be added into the html head tag when the server response the html, so I guess the async maybe is caused by SSR(this is my first SSR project), but I'm not sure.

So what I expect is the css be added into the html in the build process(i.e. it has been embed in the html when the server response the html) rather than be added when the script execute.

Comment: Be clear on your question, what you expect to happen, what doesn't happen and why those changes are negative.

Comment: @sidhuko Update the question :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any operation that will cause css to be loaded as async?

No! But it may seem like it when having implemented server-side rendering. When you launch the app, the server receives the request, renders the required component(s) into an HTML string (without css modules), and then sends it as a response to the client. From that point on, the client takes over rendering duties. This is why you see the first HTML render but without the styles and hence getting the illusion that the css is being loaded asynchronously.

> ...How to solve this correctly?

If you want to have the styles rendered with the first initial server rendering, you can use something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-css-modules-transform). This babel-plugin does what the [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) does. The output by this plugin, however, is not important for our purposes but the mapping of selectors themselves.

Assuming you have a `.babelrc` for configuration, you can update the env section like so:

```
"env": {
  "server": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "css-modules-transform", {
          "generateScopedName": "[hash:8]",
           "extensions": [".css"]
         }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

and then when building the server or (usually) in the scripts found in `package.json`, simply specify `BABEL_ENV=server` env variable to the command that builds your server, so that this plugin only runs when building the backend and not when building the client bundle.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it later

Comment: Cool. Did you find this useful?

Comment: Sorry, I'am a little busy, I will try it tomorrow